# Passing twig code expression from php

Tags: symfony, twig

Not sure if that was asked before, probably tho but could not really find any helpful answers.

Somewhere in my code I'm generating some template content with php:

```
$data = '<img src="{{ asset(\'images/logo.png\') }}" alt="My logo" />';
```

Then I'm passing it to a twig template:

```
return $this->render('SWCountryBundle:Country:list.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
```

And of course within my twig template the result is not what I expect:

```
{{ data }}
```

generates the following code in the DOM:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="My logo" />
```

Instead I'd like it to interpret the asset location and so display the image correctly.

Any ideas on how I should handle that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just pass `images/logo.png`, then write the markup? That is templates' purpose.

Comment: I agree with @moonwave99. If what you are trying to do is more complicated than the sample code you showed, you could embed a controller, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: Totally agree with above comments. What you are trying to achieve is not Symfony way

Comment: @moonwave99 - Because I made it simple here for the question but actually my $data variable contains more than just one image, it has some text and also other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I changed the way to approach things.

Content of $data was fetched from a text file, parsed to add images and stored as a single string.

Since an image needs to be inserted after the text contained by each line of the file, I decided to store those lines in an array instead, pass the array to my Twig template and so I can put the img tag directly in my template.

Every day is a school day!
And btw I don't think there are stupid questions as long as you learn something ;)